# Unable to enable CORS requests to a Google App Engine IAP

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cors, google-iap, identity-aware-proxy

Signing in users with external identities from Safari and Brave is not working. [The workaround for Safari is to disable Prevent cross-site tracking in the setting menu](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/known-issues). There is another option using gcloud iap settings set as explained in https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iap/settings/set, I tried it but I am getting this error: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Precondition check failed.

I also tried to follow the steps in https://quabr.com/59905271/how-do-you-enable-cors-requests-to-a-google-compute-engine-iap-enabled-load-bala and I get a similar error.

Answer (score 2):

Customizing IAP settings is now available **only as part of a paid enterprise security subscription** (BeyondCorp Enterprise). You can see the information from this [article](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/customizing).

That article describes how to customize Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP) settings. With these settings, you can control behaviors including:

- Compatibility with Anthos and Istio on Google Kubernetes Engine.
- The handling of CORS preflight requests.
- How users are authenticated.
- The error page shown to users when access is denied.

An alternative is that you can support CORS requests on your App Engine by [adding HTTP header](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_element) to your app.yaml, for example:

```
handlers:
- url: /
  ...
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://URL
  # ...
```

> Note: if you wanted to allow everyone to access your assets, you could use the wildcard '*', instead of your URL

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here.

I used this command a lot of times with suscess, until the last week, but dont work anymore.

```
cat > settings <<EOF
accessSettings:
  corsSettings:
    allowHttpOptions: true
EOF

gcloud iap settings set settings --project=PROJECT-ID
```

Comment: Customizing IAP is now a feature only available to BeyondCorp Enterprise users